Speed up the booting process in Ubuntu 24.04
Ubuntu 24.04 is taking too much time to boot/startup. It is dual-booted with Windows 10.
• SYSTEM INFORMATION
HOST - HP Pavilion Notebook (HP)
COMPUTER TYPE - Notebook
CPU - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U (4) @ 3.50 GHz
GPU - NVIDIA GeForce 940MX [Discrete]
GPU - Intel HD Graphics 620 @ 1.05 GHz [Integrated]
MEMORY USED - 6.94 GiB / 23.24 GiB (30%)
SWAP USED - Disabled
DISK - 124.75 GiB / 181.03 GiB (69%) - ext4
• SOFTWARE INFORMATION
DISTRO - Ubuntu noble 24.04 x86_64
KERNEL - Linux 6.8.0-44-generic

$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 5.129s (kernel) + 2min 20.660s (userspace) = 2min 25.790s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 20.600s in userspace.

And systemd-analyze blame gives the following:
1min 31.848s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     19.287s plymouth-read-write.service
     17.153s e2scrub_reap.service
     15.619s dev-sda8.device
     15.525s apport.service
     14.874s plymouth-start.service
     14.079s NetworkManager.service
     13.656s preload.service
      9.986s gnome-remote-desktop.service
      9.063s accounts-daemon.service
      7.975s nmbd.service
      6.742s udisks2.service
      6.415s samba-ad-dc.service
      6.179s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      5.965s power-profiles-daemon.service
      5.913s loadcpufreq.service
      5.911s polkit.service
      5.817s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.501s bluetooth.service
      4.610s systemd-udevd.service
      4.379s ModemManager.service
      4.291s smbd.service
      4.122s apparmor.service
      3.965s mnt-2C58207458203EC8.mount
      3.699s gpu-manager.service
      3.692s fwupd.service
      3.605s rsyslog.service
      3.454s avahi-daemon.service
      3.318s mnt-8C34519E34518C58.mount
      3.295s smartmontools.service
      3.279s dbus.service
      3.044s wpa_supplicant.service
      2.882s cups.service
      2.735s mnt-76BC3AD3BC3A8E1D.mount
      2.640s pulseaudio-enable-autospawn.service
      2.523s thermald.service
      2.472s systemd-resolved.service
      2.298s mnt-0626467126466233.mount
      2.032s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      1.735s gdm.service
      1.508s upower.service
      1.275s systemd-sysctl.service
      1.253s grub-common.service
      1.233s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
      1.214s nvidia-persistenced.service
      1.115s systemd-logind.service
      1.056s systemd-modules-load.service
       883ms ua-timer.service
       721ms keyboard-setup.service
       696ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       692ms user@1000.service
       650ms systemd-oomd.service
       602ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
       585ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       474ms lm-sensors.service
       453ms switcheroo-control.service
       383ms systemd-random-seed.service
       377ms apt-daily.service
       373ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       299ms update-notifier-download.service
       295ms systemd-journald.service
       267ms systemd-binfmt.service
       231ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       226ms dev-hugepages.mount
       221ms dev-mqueue.mount
       215ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       211ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
       196ms modprobe@drm.service
       195ms modprobe@fuse.service
       188ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       185ms modprobe@configfs.service
       166ms colord.service
       150ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       142ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
       129ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
       126ms kerneloops.service
       118ms ufw.service
       117ms console-setup.service
        91ms hddtemp.service
        88ms rtkit-daemon.service
        69ms openvpn.service
        57ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
        47ms setvtrgb.service
        39ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        35ms fwupd-refresh.service
        31ms alsa-restore.service
        29ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
        23ms modprobe@dm_mod.service
        22ms modprobe@loop.service
        15ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
        15ms cpufrequtils.service
        14ms sys-kernel-config.mount
        11ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
        10ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         9ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         8ms systemd-rfkill.service

Which applications can be removed or disabled to reduce the timing? Is there any tool to automate the optimization of the booting process?

Using the suggestion (GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" ") from the comment (Speed up the booting process in Ubuntu 24.04):
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 4.799s (kernel) + 1min 37.209s (userspace) = 1min 42.008s 
graphical.target reached after 55.238s in userspace.

$ systemd-analyze blame
20.669s e2scrub_reap.service
19.965s apport.service
19.548s preload.service
12.803s accounts-daemon.service
12.437s udisks2.service
12.380s gnome-remote-desktop.service
12.274s iio-sensor-proxy.service
11.986s mnt-2C58207458203EC8.mount
11.860s power-profiles-daemon.service
11.819s polkit.service
11.482s NetworkManager.service
10.615s dev-sda8.device
10.367s mnt-8C34519E34518C58.mount
 9.722s avahi-daemon.service
 9.626s dbus.service
 8.987s switcheroo-control.service
 8.938s thermald.service
 8.580s mnt-76BC3AD3BC3A8E1D.mount
 8.565s nmbd.service
 8.115s bluetooth.service
 8.038s loadcpufreq.service
 7.583s samba-ad-dc.service
 6.751s gpu-manager.service
 6.743s mnt-0626467126466233.mount
 6.117s ModemManager.service
 5.885s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 5.491s rsyslog.service
 5.345s fwupd.service
 4.965s apparmor.service
 4.680s pulseaudio-enable-autospawn.service
 4.434s smartmontools.service
 3.319s smbd.service
 2.992s grub-common.service
 2.658s systemd-udevd.service
 2.444s systemd-resolved.service
 2.239s wpa_supplicant.service
 2.216s cups.service
 2.002s grub-initrd-fallback.service
 1.925s nvidia-persistenced.service
 1.578s gdm.service
 1.569s upower.service
 1.468s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
 1.390s systemd-logind.service
 1.299s lm-sensors.service
 1.023s systemd-rfkill.service
  952ms systemd-modules-load.service
  946ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
  800ms keyboard-setup.service
  674ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
  620ms packagekit.service
  595ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  528ms systemd-journald.service
  489ms systemd-oomd.service
  460ms systemd-sysctl.service
  393ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  380ms user@1000.service
  323ms systemd-remount-fs.service
  312ms systemd-random-seed.service
  199ms colord.service
  165ms kerneloops.service
  163ms systemd-binfmt.service
  140ms setvtrgb.service
  130ms plymouth-read-write.service
  127ms systemd-update-utmp.service
  112ms console-setup.service
  106ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  101ms openvpn.service
   98ms ufw.service
   77ms hddtemp.service
   72ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   67ms dev-mqueue.mount
   66ms dev-hugepages.mount
   65ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   64ms rtkit-daemon.service
   63ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
   59ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
   52ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   50ms modprobe@configfs.service
   50ms modprobe@loop.service
   45ms modprobe@dm_mod.service
   44ms modprobe@drm.service
   37ms modprobe@fuse.service
   18ms cpufrequtils.service
   16ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
   16ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
   14ms alsa-restore.service
   10ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
    9ms sys-kernel-config.mount
    8ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
    6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
    5ms plymouth-quit-wait.service

It shows the processes and logs on the screen which I don't like. Also, note that the disk mount time was 3.965s mnt-2C58207458203EC8.mount previously, now it has become 11.986s mnt-2C58207458203EC8.mount. Why has it been affected and increased this much?

I have disabled the service NetworkManager-wait-online.service as suggested (Speed up the booting process in Ubuntu 24.04). But I couldn't disable mounts in the same way. And I don't prefer the behavior obtained by unmarking the option Mount at system startup from Gnome Disc Utility Disks, as discussed (Speed up the booting process in Ubuntu 24.04). What else can I do?

Edit /etc/default/grub  to disable the splash screen. find this line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" , replace it with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="  ", save the file, sudo update-grub, reboot, and analyze again.

@TalaatEtman I have updated the question.

disable mnt-2C58207458203EC8.mount, mnt-8C34519E34518C58.mount,  mnt-76BC3AD3BC3A8E1D.mount,  mnt-0626467126466233.mount,  and NetworkManager-wait-online.service.

can you suggest how to disable them? like if I disable them, do I need to manually enable them after booting each time?

use sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service. you don't need to enable this service after booting, if there is a need for this service it will be enabled by the system. the mount points can be disabled by the disk utility, or remove *.mount from etc/systemd/system directories, or use sudo systemctle disabe *.mount.

sudo systemctl disable *.mount gives Glob pattern passed to enable, but globs are not supported for this. Invalid unit name "*.mount" escaped as "\x2a.mount". Failed to disable unit: Unit file \x2a.mount does not exist.

Also, I tried with sudo systemctl disable mnt-2C58207458203EC8.mount, it shows: https://i.sstatic.net/AUxNkp8J.png

open /etc/systemd/system as administrator, remove mnt-2C58207458203EC8.mount, mnt-8C34519E34518C58.mount, mnt-76BC3AD3BC3A8E1D.mount, and mnt-0626467126466233.mount.

I am confused about where to look for the *.mount bcz here etc/systemd/system is a directory that contains: https://i.sstatic.net/jya8LUKF.png

Can I change it from here (https://i.sstatic.net/pBmx5Znf.png ) in the Disks app's Mount options?

yes, use disk utility, and remove the mark of mount at system startup

Ok, I did it. But it doesn't have much significance, like now: Startup finished in 4.942s (kernel) + 1min 37.332s (userspace) = 1min 42.274s  graphical.target reached after 43.896s in userspace.
And I realize I prefer mount them at system startup, otherwise, the specific folders I have bookmarked from those drives can't be found/opened unless I mount them back manually. I prefer to use a method to auto-enable the mounts after booting.
